# text colour in GB image not correct

Tags: php, gd

I have the following code which creates an image based on whats in a mySQL db based on what has been uploaded via a form

```
if($bg_img){
        list($img_width, $img_height, $img_type, $img_attr) = getimagesize('./images/'.$bg_img);
    }
    // Use image in background
    $im = imagecreatefrompng(IS_DIR."/images/".$bg_img);

    $fn = rgb2array($font_color);       
    $font_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $fn[0], $fn[1], $fn[2]);
```

This creates the image then assigns a font colour, and later in the code, text is added etc. All that works fine.

I have a strange issue though. I have two 8 bit PNG's. One of them is just a plain grey colour, the other one is an actual graphical image with a logo on it. If I use the basic one, the text uses the colour I have defined in $font_color (which comes from DB) without issues. If I use the more graphical one, the colour is incorrect and the imagecollorallocate doesn't seem to return a set of RGB values.

Is there something that needs to be done with certain types of PNG?

Comment: I don't know what you need to do about it, but I imagine the problem is with "indexed" PNGs - images where rather than storing the exact colour at each pixel, a palette is stored at the beginning of the file. A colour not in the palette can't be represented in such a file, so you'd need to add it to the palette first.

Comment: Thanks. That might be an insurmountable issue then. The image used will be uploaded by average users who wouldn't know about saving PNG's in a certain way to get around that. I exported both PNG's from Photoshop with exactly the same settings. The only difference was the look of the image.